# How i can refresh the same activity in static method

Tags: java, android

My application need to close the activity and open it directly using refresh activity or open new activity and back to the activity ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static TextView messageBox;
    static String x="";
    static Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         messageBox=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageBox);
         check();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


     public static void updateMessageBox(String msg,String from)
        {
            messageBox.append(msg);
            //Get parent phone number from database
            //check parent number with ...
            if(msg.equals("enable wifi"))
            {
                x="yes";
            }
            //context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));

            Intent i=new Intent(context, p1.class);
            context.startActivity(i);

          }

     private void check()
     {

         if(x.equals("yes"))
         {
             WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
              wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
         }

     }


}
```

i'm using open new activity and back to the activity but work crash for application  !!

please help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

OR

if your application minimum API > 11 then you can call `Activity.recreate();`
This is preferable if you're in an API11+ environment. You can still check the current version and call the code snippet above if you're in API 10 or below. (Please don't forget to upvote Ralf's answer!)

Comment: that is the same answer that i gave :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

to refresh an activity from within itself.

Comment: please post the logcat if it is crashing

Comment: can't run on emulator,only on phone

Comment: yes but when you run it on your phone from eclipse/intellij/android studio, you have a logcat that shows you the errors/warnings/etc.

Comment: How are you testing you application on device ?

Comment: run application direct ,send sms between two divice